# LinqtoTwitter TweetAsync never returns in ServiceStack App

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, async-await, linq-to-twitter

When using LinqToTwitter the status update gets posted to twitter with no problems, however the route times out and when debugging the if statement after the await line the debugger never reaches that point.  What can I do to fix this?

```
async public Task<object> Post(RetweetPost retweetInfo){

...


var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
{
  CredentialStore = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentialStore
  {
    ConsumerKey = "ConsumerKey",
    ConsumerSecret = "ConsumerSecret",
    AccessToken = account.OAuthToken,
    AccessTokenSecret = account.OAuthTokenSecret
  }
};

var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);

var tweet = await twitterCtx.TweetAsync(retweetInfo.tweet);

//DOES NOT REACH THIS LINE
if (tweet != null)
{
    return new RetweetPostResponse
    {
        twitterTweetId = tweet.StatusID.ToString()
    };
}
```

Comment: pls try putting a catch block and make sure no error is thrown .

Comment: What does you mean by "never reached"? Does it hang? Does it continue to execute outside the method? Do you have "CLR Exceptions" enabled in the exception window in VS?

Comment: If it truly hangs (with not error) there might be a bug in the client, and you should then look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21468137/885318

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the real problem I was facing was the ServiceStack Framework.  As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251904/servicestack-new-api-and-async-await).  Apparently async functions on routes were not supported until ServiceStack 4.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a call to `Task<T>.Result` or `Task.Wait` further up your call stack. This will [cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I describe in detail on my blog.

`await` will capture a "context" by default (e.g., a UI context) and use that to resume the `async` method. When the `TweetAsync` task completes, it attempts to resume within that context (e.g., on the UI thread), but it can't because there's already a thread blocked in that context (i.e., calling `Result`/`Wait`).

The best solution is to replace all `Result` and `Wait` calls with `await`.

Comment: I normally don't like guessing answers this type of question is really just always due to the same issue.